# How to assign unique colors to multiple vertical lines in R forestplot?

Tags: r, r-grid, r-forestplot

I am using forestplot and want to put a series of vertical lines in the figure.  I am successful adding as many lines as I want, using the `grid` argument. But, I would like to assign a different color to each line, and so far I can only get them to share the same color.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forestplot)

df <- data.frame(
  model_name = rep(c('A','B','C','D'),3),
  group = c(rep("Qrt 2",4),rep("Qrt 3",4),rep("Qrt 4",4)),
  mean =  c(10, 9.5,  10.5,  11, 5, 4.75, 5.25, 5.05, 2,   1.9, 1.8, 1.7),
  lower = c(9,  8.5,  9.5,   10, 4, 4,    4.5,  4.25, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 1.65),
  upper = c(11, 10.5, 10.75, 12, 6, 5,    5.5,  5.8,  2.3, 2.2, 1.9, 1.75)
)

df |>
  group_by(group) |>
  forestplot(
    title = "Test Forest Plot",
    labeltext = model_name,
    boxsize = 0.2,
    vertices = TRUE,
    grid = structure(c(df[1,3], df[5,3], df[9,3]),
                     gp = gpar(lty = c(1,2,2), # line types other than the first one are ignored!
                               col = c("blue","green","red")))) |> # red and green are ignored!
  fp_set_style(box = c("blue", "green", "red"), # no problems with these colors, tho
               line = c("blue", "green", "red")) |>
  fp_add_header(model_name = c("Model")) |>
  fp_add_lines(h_2 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_3 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_4 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_5 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_6 = gpar(lwd = 1))
```

Result:

[image: Forest plot but the 3 vertical lines are all blue]

The 3 added vertical lines are all blue, but I want them to be blue, green, and red, corresponding to the color of the respective `group` (i.e, blue, green, red, from right to left).  I don't care about the gray zero line, I'm ignoring it for now.

I've tried various permutations of structure(), c(), and list() encompassing the arguments passed to `grid`, but no luck so far.  I've also experimented with fpColor:
`col = fpColors(vrtcl_lines = c("blue","green","red"))`
But, same lack of results.

It would also be nice to individually control line types, and I'm hoping that if I can solve the color problem, then the line type problem can be solved analogously.

Can anyone advise me how, if it's possible? Thanks for your consideration.
*(edit: made color order consistent in the text)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `shapes_gp` of the `forestplot()` function using a `fpShapesGp` object, which controls the graphical parameters of all the non-text elements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forestplot)

# Create your 'styles'
styles <- fpShapesGp(grid = list(
      gpar(lty = 1, col = "blue"),
      gpar(lty = 2, col = "green"),
      gpar(lty = 2, col = "red")))

# Provide your 'styles' to shapes_gp
df |>
  group_by(group) |>
  forestplot(
    title = "Test Forest Plot",
    labeltext = model_name,
    boxsize = 0.2,
    vertices = TRUE,
    grid = c(df[1,3], df[5,3], df[9,3]),
    shapes_gp = styles) |>
  fp_set_style(box = c("blue", "green", "red"),
               line = c("blue", "green", "red")) |>
  fp_add_header(model_name = c("Model")) |>
  fp_add_lines(h_2 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_3 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_4 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_5 = gpar(lwd = 1),
               h_6 = gpar(lwd = 1))
```

[image: shapes_gp-styles]

---

**Raw data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  model_name = rep(c('A','B','C','D'),3),
  group = c(rep("Qrt 2",4),rep("Qrt 3",4),rep("Qrt 4",4)),
  mean =  c(10, 9.5,  10.5,  11, 5, 4.75, 5.25, 5.05, 2,   1.9, 1.8, 1.7),
  lower = c(9,  8.5,  9.5,   10, 4, 4,    4.5,  4.25, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 1.65),
  upper = c(11, 10.5, 10.75, 12, 6, 5,    5.5,  5.8,  2.3, 2.2, 1.9, 1.75)
)
```